# jQuery test if form fields aren't empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know this might sound like a basic question but I have the following code to test that a form's fields aren't empty:

```
$('.button_overlay').mouseover(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#field1").val()) != "" && $.trim($("#field2").val()) != "") {
        $('.button_overlay').css('display', 'none');
    }
 });
```

But I keep getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error. I'm not sure why this isn't valid though. Anyone able to give some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: That code works fine, the error is coming from somewhere else. Can you post a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: You might have an illegal character somewhere in your code. Post the jsFiddle so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I really couldn't find what the issue was so I just created a nested `if` statement within the main `if` statement. This achieves the same effect as the `&&`.